# Load data from app accros site-wide footer

Tags: django, django-templates

I have an app called sponsors.
The model contains a field gold sponsor which is a boolean.
Now I want to load the gold sponsors in the site-wide footer which is included in my base.html

How can I make the data from the app sponsors available in the footer?

```
    <footer>
        {% include "includes/footer.html" %}
    </footer>
```

Comment: Either you can use django middlewares or you can use session to load data site wide

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a `context_processor` to make the variables in `footer` available site-wide.

An example:

**app/context_processors.py**

```
def footer_vars(request):
    return {"date": timezone.now()}
```

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            ...
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'app.context_processors.footer_vars',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```